# Thor source paths for template method

Tags: ruby, thor

I'm trying use Thor template method. But when I wrote spec for my case, it turns out that script didn't see templates directory

#### Directory structure

```
/crx
  /lib
    /templates
      manifest
    command.rb
```

#### Thor task implementation inside command.rb

```
module Crx
  class Command < Thor
    include Thor::Actions

    def self.source_root
      File.dirname(__FILE__)
    end

    desc "add", "add extension files like manifest, content_script"
    def add(name)
      template 'templates/manifest'
    end

  end
end
```

#### Failed spec

```
Crx::Command should create manifest
  Thor::Error:
    Could not find "templates/manifest" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are: 
    /home/lewy/Programowanie/ruby/crx/lib/crx
```

Comment: It seems you have to set destination_root as well.

Comment: same problem as well. if only a solution was here!?